# No count method on an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, count

I'm using the select method on a DataTable within a DataSet to return an array of DataRows. This works fine, but on my array I **don't** have a Count method??

I can't understand why, I've used almost the exact statement within another application and I do have the Count method.

I've checked the reference to System.Data in both apps and they are the same. I've also checked the using statement at the top of the class and they are both set the same. i.e. using System.Data;

Here is my code:

```
DataRow[] selectedRecords = myDataset.Tables["Records"].Select();
```

now I'm trying to do :

```
selectedRecords.Count()
```

but I have no Count Method!?!?!

I'm using C# 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use Array.Length, not Count. Arrays do not have a Count property. If you are trying to use LINQ's Count() method specifically, you should import the System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 5):

Arrays use `Length`. However, if you import the Linq namespace, there is a `Count()` extension method.

Comment: P.S. @user1131657 if ever need to use Linq to `.Count()` an array's length, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for

```
selectedRecords.Length;
```

Answer (score 4):

1. To be able to `.Count()` an array, you need a `using System.Linq;` to be in force
2. Or you could just use `.Length`...

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the `Length` property as others explained, an array also implements the `IList` interface, which in turn implements `ICollection` which defines a `Count` property. However, it is implemented explicitly in arrays, which means that you can access it only through the interface

```
public int GetCountOf(ICollection coll) {
    return coll.Count;
}

...

int cnt = GetCountOf(myArray);
```

Or

```
int cnt = ((ICollection)myArray).Count;
```

`Count` here returns the length of the array and not the count of the items contained in the array, i.e. the array could have all `null` entries.

Comment: In second example application gain a boxing penalty.

Comment: @Rudolf Dvoracek: Boxing only applies to value types, not to reference types like arrays. Both examples have to cast to `ICollection`.

Comment: I forgot, thank you @Olivier Jacot-Descombes for fixing my note.